# Help with fractions

Tags: fractions

I have attached an image of which I have a question about. I don’t understand how you can get from equation 1 to equation 2.

Could someone please explain this?

$$nRc=\left(\frac{V_{cc}-V_{BE}}{V_o-V_{BE}}\right)R_B-R_B\tag{1}$$

$$nRc=\frac{V_{cc}R_B-V_{BE}R_B-V_oR_B+V_{BE}R_B}{V_o-V_{BE}}\tag{2}$$

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: Just don’t understand the mathematical steps taken to get from equation 1 to 2

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yeah Shaun, I'm going to have to start using it at some stage, its very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have done three operations in one.

The first operation is to carry out the multiplication
$$
\left(\frac{V_{CC} - V_{BE}}{V_0 - V_{BE}}\right)R_B = \frac{V_{CC}R_B - V_{BE}R_B}{V_0 - V_{BE}}
$$
The second thing they did was to subtract the rightmost $R_B$ from this resulting fraction, which is a two-step process.

The first step in fraction addition and subtraction is to make sure all involved fractions have the same denominator. So we rewrite $R_B$ into a fraction with $V_0 - V_{BE}$ in the denominator:
$$
R_B = \frac{ (V_0 - V_{BE})\cdot R_B}{V_0 - V_{BE}} = \frac{V_0R_B - V_{BE}R_B}{V_0 - V_{BE}}
$$
Then you subtract the two fractions from one another by simply subtracting the numerators and keeping the denominator unchanged (be careful with the signs in the second fraction here):
$$
\frac{V_{CC}R_B - V_{BE}R_B}{V_0 - V_{BE}} - \frac{V_0R_B - V_{BE}R_B}{V_0 - V_{BE}}\\
= \frac{V_{CC}R_B - V_{BE}R_B - (V_0R_B - V_{BE}R_B)}{V_0 - V_{BE}}
\\
= \frac{V_{CC}R_B - V_{BE}R_B - V_0R_B + V_{BE}R_B}{V_0 - V_{BE}}
$$
And that's it.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, get it now. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is $$\frac{V_{CC}-V{BE}}{V_0-V_{BE}}R_B-R_B=\frac{(V_{CC}-V_{BE})R_B-R_B(V_0-V_{BE})}{V_0-V_{BE}}$$

Comment: Thank you Dr Sonnhard, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{V_{CC}-V_{BE}}{V_O-V_{BE}}R_B-R_B=
\frac{R_B(V_{CC}-V_{BE})}{V_O-V_{BE}}-R_B=\\
\frac{V_{CC} R_B-V_{BE} R_B}{V_O-V_{BE}}-R_B=
\frac{V_{CC} R_B-V_{BE} R_B}{V_O-V_{BE}}-R_B\frac{V_O-V_{BE}}{V_O-V_{BE}}=\\
\frac{V_{CC} R_B-V_{BE} R_B-R_B(V_O-V_{BE})}{V_O-V_{BE}}=\\
\frac{V_{CC} R_B-V_{BE} R_B-V_O R_B+V_{BE} R_B}{V_O-V_{BE}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Michael, I understand it now.